# ASP.NET Web API 2.0 pipeline and ASP.NET Core Web API pipeline differences

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I recently started migrating my app from Web.Api .NET standard to .Net Core.

First of all are all the steps of the Web Api pipeline still there?

When i say all the steps i mean :
[Web api pipeline Poster](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf)

In terms of usage i can see the filters are applied  through the

```
 [ServiceFilter(typeof(NameOfAttribute))]
```

But in a variety of articles like this one :
https://andrewlock.net/asp-net-core-in-action-filters/

i can see different kind of filters like **resource** and **results** filters.

Also i cannot see the usage of Delegating Handlers.

Where should we integrate the functionality of the previous pipeline with the new standards?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since classic `Asp.Net` and `Asp.Net core` are cognate technologies there are many common concepts in a request processing, but there are some differences and most likely you will have to rewrite some stuff in your project.

As you noted there are new filters. They allow to handle request in more granular approach. You can use filters as you did it before just by decorating actions and controllers:

```
[SomeFilter]
public IActionResult SomeAction(){...}
```

And (as before in classic `Asp.Net`) you can't use dependency injection through the filter constructor. Filters applied like that behave like a singleton. One instance is used for all requests.

`ServiceFilterAttribute` and `TypeFilterAttribute` allow to use the dependency injection through the filter constructor. Optionally filters applied like that can behave like singletons or can be created every time (with dependency injection) for every request. You can adjust it by using `IsReusable` property. Read more about filter [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

There are no more `Delegating Handlers`. Instead of you can create a custom `middleware`. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105154/4242590).

Comment: Just adding to the answer this article :    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-2.2